# How to parse data from textarea by line break and concatenate

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to parse the value from a textarea based on linebreaks and have it converted into one string replacing a line break with a concat character like ;

Basically I want something like:

```
Hello World
My Name is Carl
I like apples
```

To:

```
"Hello World;My name is Carl;I like apples"
```

I'm wanting to submit it to a text column in a database and then when I retrieve the data later for viewing I want it to parse back to line-breaks using the ; as the identifier character. I'm using CodeIgniter so if there are any helper functions I can use that would be neat.

Comment: why can't you use nl2br. It will all your problem. You dont want to add ";" and remove when display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you dont want to add `";"` or anything. You want to show what your getting. Then use `nl2br`

```
$text = nl2br($this->input->post("textarea_name"));
```

store it in db and display directly without additional code.